# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function smileysboxrep() on a non-object in

Tags: php

When I add a PHP function, it shows me the above error on the server error page. Where is my problem?

smileysboxall.php

```
class kochClass {

     function smileysboxrep($Sid){
echo'<img src="../smile.gif" alt=":)" class="embtno" id="'.$Sid.'" />
     <img src="../sad.gif" alt=":(" class="embtno" id="'.$Sid.'" />
     <img src="../biggrin.gif" alt=":-D" class="embtno" id="'.$Sid.'" />';
     }

     function smileysboxcom($id){
echo'<img src="../smile.gif" alt=":)" class="embtn" id="'.$id.'" />
     <img src="../sad.gif" alt=":(" class="embtn" id="'.$id.'" />
     <img src="../biggrin.gif" alt=":-D" class="embtn" id="'.$id.'" />';
     }
}
$kochClass = new kochClass();
```

Call function at index.php

```
// Query and echoing
$Sid = $rows['s_id'];
include_once("smileysboxall.php");
if ($Sid){ echo ''.$kochClass->smileysboxrep($Sid).'';}
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `include_once`.

Actually `include_once` is going to include your code just once and maybe in another file so your `$kochClass = new kochClass();` doesn't exists in index.php.

Just move `$kochClass = new kochClass();` in index.php .

Comment: I don't know why but his code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Probably it is because of the `include_once()` story because I do it all in the same file to test.